# Visual Studio Community 2015 Services not available

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The problem is that I can't sign in to my visual studio, so can't use it.

My 30 day license expired and that means that I have to sign in in order to use it.
So I hit Sign in button. A white window saying "We're getting things ready" shows up and after a while labled: "Sorry, we ran into a problem", saying "The online service is not available. Please try again later.".

When I checked the service status, it said it is online.

**EDIT:**
{

I just used [**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com) to debug the network connection.. and I found out that the program or even the system just can't establish the connection to this server: **http://go.microsoft.com:443**

}

Any ideas how to fix it and sign in?

Comment: It's better to ask MS support to help troubleshoot this problem. Many network issue may cause this problem and they more knowledge about it.

Comment: somebody had the exactly same problem.. but no solution

Comment: @tom Just as a last resort !! Try to disable Antivirus if you have any and check to signin

Comment: Did this failure happen with or without fiddler installed? Many network problems are solved when fiddler is uninstalled.

Comment: @Webruster That didn't work! I completely disabled the Windows Defender Even!

Comment: @qxg Yes, I installed fiddler to see where is the problem.

Comment: I have fiddler and wireshark installed the answer posted by @Greg Naidu worked for me

Comment: I had the same problem. But I exit Kaspersky AntiVirus, and then was able to sign in without any problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the Visual Studio proxy settings in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config

to

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Well I already installed win 7 again and it's working without any fixes..
But I will mark this as an Answer to this question :).

Comment: life saver!  I had a 2012 R2 server with VS2015Community installed that could neither use Nuget nor login for licensing.  this fixed both issues.  our config had NO nodes for proxy... so I added what was above here and it worked just fine.  thanks!!!

Comment: I do think, that Fiddler messed proxy settings up. This solution helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is a bit of a necro, but I fixed the above problem with a simple ipconfig /release, /renew, /flushdns in the command prompt. Works just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control panel > Internet options > Connections > LAN settings : 
Check proxy settings, may be wrong settings.

Comment: Upvoted as this answer was recorded prior to the identical answer (copy & pasted ?) by Kumar.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for us We have changed the proxy.Go to Control panel > Internet options > Connections > LAN settings : Check proxy settings, may be wrong settings.

Answer (score 0):

The URL http://go.microsoft.com:443 is telling the browser to use NON-SSL protocol over the SSL port. Adding an s to the http, making the url https://go.microsoft.com:443 works fine for me.

I still can't get my visual studio to do anything network related though, which is a pain as it's registered to my MSDN and has timed out now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that happened because I have Fiddler installed an I had changed machine.config in order to add defaultProxy and track requests made within visual studio debugging

This is the paged that instructed me how to do it:

http://www.telerik.com/blogs/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler

After disabling the defaultProxy in machine.config it worked again!